# AS3 core packages reference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, reference, package

I'm teaching myself actionScript 3.
I'm having some difficulty knowing which packages / classes to import from the flash core.

I'm still a little shaky on the terminology but I mean these statements at the start of the main AS file.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
```

Are there any good references / cheatsheets that describe what each flash.example.example provides? At least for commonly used packages.

edit: A little more searching and I'm now fairly certain I'm talking about importing packages.

Comment: You may be interested in this website as well: http://gotoandlearn.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just talking about Adobe's LiveDocs? Because that's easy enough to find by searching:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package-summary.html

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date version that covers Flash Player 10: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-summary.html

Comment: Cheers. Precisely what I wanted.

Comment: Use Matt's link. There's like a million versions of the language reference for every release of Flash. They're all exactly the same except for like two updated pages.

Comment: When working with beta versions of flash or beta features use the beta language reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use FlashDevelop, it will import a lot of stuff automatically
2. General way to go about this
   -> Find what you want from "http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/" or the tutorial
   -> Import it.
3. I like to import flash.display.MovieClip